# How do i fetch Badge details and User details while comparing two similar records in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | USER | PROFILE |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  |  A   |  Water  |
| 2  |  B   |  Fire   |
| 3  |  C   |  Air    |
| 4  |  A   |  Fire   |
| 5  |  B   |  Air    |
+----+------+---------+
```

How do i get my output as

```
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | USER | PROFILE-A | PROFILE-B |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  |  A   |  Water    |   Fire    |
| 2  |  B   |  Fire     |   Air     |
+----+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have tried this query and i am able to pull only the user ID details,

```
SELECT A.ID 
FROM  
       (SELECT ID 
        FROM   Sheet1 
        WHERE  Profile = 'Water') A, 
       (SELECT ID 
        FROM   Sheet1 
        WHERE  Profile = 'Air') B 
WHERE  A.ID=B.ID;
```

Comment: You should use `JOIN`.. and are you sure it's `WHERE  A.ID=B.ID`? Isn't suppose to be `WHERE  A.user=B.user`?

Comment: From what I get you want to print all profiles per user right?

Answer (score 2):

From the example you have provided (Data at the start and expected data) this query will give you the exact ersult:

```
select min(t1.id) as 'ID'
       , t1.user as 'USER' 
       , max(t1.PROFILE) as 'PROFILE-A'
       , min(t2.PROFILE) as 'PROFILE-B'
from Sheet1 t1
left join Sheet1 t2 on t1.USER = t2.USER
and t1.PROFILE <> t2.PROFILE
group by t1.user
having count(t1.user) > 1
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f26512c299adf4f233aeef7471c1b65).

Comment: So, @ArunV, is this ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, you can get your results by joining on `user` and filtering out same profiles:

```
SELECT A.id, A.user, A.profile, B.profile
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM sheet1) as A, 
  (SELECT * FROM sheet1) as B
 WHERE 
  A.user = B.user 
  AND A.profile <> B.profile
 GROUP BY A.user;
```

The same thing can be written as (a bit newer syntax):

```
SELECT B.id, B.user, B.profile, A.profile
FROM sheet1 A
JOIN sheet1 B on A.user=B.user
WHERE A.profile <> B.profile
GROUP BY B.user
ORDER BY B.id;
```

However, note that these queries will be very inefficient if you table gets too large. An alternative to avoid the join would be:

```
SELECT id, user, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(profile))
FROM sheet1
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(profile) > 1
ORDER BY id;
```

This way, you are not joining on anything and the query should be a lot faster on larger datasets. However, the 3rd column will be a comma-separated list of profile names for each user

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/773959/46/0

Comment: OP provided a example data (that we begin with and end with). First two examples will not provide a correct answer according to that example data as you can check here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=483bfe1ce9d93e4ae06b13449487a3cc.  And the third example will not eliminate the C user and it will give only one column...

Comment: @VBoka Thanks! Attention to detail I see :). I have modified the queries to match the results as close as possible. Note that interestingly enough, in query 2 order of things changed! My main point was to provide a solution that avoids join rather than the exact result - but nice catch

Comment: Hi, you are welcome, well :) I have checked and I see group by is not correct in first and second example.